# What kind of Indicator is this?

Tags: indicators

I am including the image for reference.

[image: Indicator]

It seems like a mix of supertrend with some averaging in line plotting.

Comment: Impossible to answer. Ask whoever you got it from.

Answer (score 1):

It a Step Indicator.  It's impossible to know what the specific basis is from a graph.  Check the source.